# Running Grails database migrations manually from

Tags: grails, war, database-migration

I have a requirement that I cannot autorun grails migration -- they should be run under user supervision.

Complicating this matter is the fact that the artifact of deployment is a war.

Is there a way to manually run the migrations from the exploded war?

It seems like it might be possible with some groovy magic and MigrationRunner, but sure if there's a covered approach.

I've searched high and low and not found much in the way of this.

Comment: you can just type 'grails dbm-update' from the command line.  If you need to do it on a specific environment, add '-Dgrails.env=whatever' to the command.

Comment: @Gregg would that work while in the directory of an exploded war though? It doesn't have the same structure as the app in development.

Comment: Aadi D, You can have the migrations plugin just produce the SQL for you, then it can be run at anytime. The command is `dbm-update-sql`